# 403 forbidden with simple Android Picasa album list request

Tags: android, picasa

I'm having a terrible time accessing Picasa from Android. After hours of researching, I finally determined that the [Google API Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) library is what I should be using. Several hours later and I divined that I have to use Mercurial and Maven to download and build a [sample client](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default) so that I can get certain secret libraries that aren't included in the [download instructions](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup). And of course the sample client is in no way compatible with and only slightly resembles that in the [Picasa Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html).

So after much trouble I create a simple URL and try to list albums for a user, using code from the sample client:

```
PicasaUrl url = PicasaUrl.relativeToRoot("feed/api/user/someuser");
UserFeed userFeed = client.executeGetUserFeed(url);
```

Now the actual URL this creates is something like:

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/someuser?prettyprint=true
```

If I put this in my browser, it works fine. In my Android client, however, it gives me an HTTP 403 forbidden error. And no, I can't even run the sample client, because it doesn't give me an APK file. (Plus the source code isn't documented, is written like spaghetti, and uses deprecated methods.)

After turning on protocol-level logging, it turns out that this is the HTTP request being sent:

```
GET https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/someuser?fields=author/name,entry(@gd:etag,category(@scheme,@term),gphoto:access,gphoto:numphotos,link(@href,@rel),summary,title,updated),link(@href,@rel),openSearch:totalResults&kinds=album&max-results=3&prettyprint=false
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=null
User-Agent: MyApp/1.0 Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.6.0-beta (gzip)
GData-Version: 2
```

Where in the Sam Hill did all that crap come from? But you know what? The URL still works in my browser. This must be something about the Authorization: header.

After much more pain, I managed to modify the authentication from the sample so that a notification would appear and allow the user to authenticate the account. Now I'm able to list albums.

But I still don't understand: how can I list the public albums without authentication?